# Como hacer editable una variable de un plugin de Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Tengo un plugin en PHP, y necesito que la variable $login_page del siguiente código, pueda ser editable para poder cambiar el valor URL de la variable.

El código del plugin:

```
function redirect_login_page() {
  $login_page  = home_url( 'url/fichero.php' );
  $page_viewed = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

  if( $page_viewed == "wp-login.php" && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
    wp_redirect($login_page);
    exit;
  }
}
add_action('init','redirect_login_page');
```

Una solución podría ser que tenga un editor dentro del panel de administración de Wordpress y con un campo de texto donde pueda introducir la URL que quiera y que esta modifique esa variable. ¿Es posible?

Comment: estas buscando redireccionar luego del login exitoso a una url? sólo administradores, sólo usuarios, o todo el mundo?

Comment: A priori a todo el mundo.

Comment: queres armar un panel o agregarlo a alguna categoria/submenu de settings?

Comment: Tienes un editor ahí en WordPress, la URL la pones ahí en el mismo código